# Gracefully closing channel and not sending on closed channel

Tags: go, concurrency

I am new to Golang concurrency and have been working to understand this piece of code mentioned below.

I witness few things which I am unable to explain why it happens:

1. when using i smaller than equal to 100000 `for i <= 100000 {` in main function, it sometimes prints different values for nResults and countWrites (in last two statements)
   `fmt.Printf("number of result writes %d\n", nResults) fmt.Printf("Number of job writes %d\n", jobWrites)`
2. when using i more than 1000000 it gives `panic: send on closed channel`

How can I make sure that the values send to jobs is not on closed channel and later after all values are received in results we can close the channel without deadlock?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int, countWrites *int64) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for j := range jobs {
        *countWrites += 1
        go func(j int) {
            if j%2 == 0 {
                results <- j * 2
            } else {
                results <- j
            }
        }(j)
    }
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    jobs := make(chan int)
    results := make(chan int)
    var i int = 1
    var jobWrites int64 = 0
    for i <= 10000000 {
        go func(j int) {
            if j%2 == 0 {
                i += 99
                j += 99
            }
            jobWrites += 1
            jobs <- j
        }(i)
        i += 1
    }

    var nResults int64 = 0
    for w := 1; w < 1000; w++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(wg, w, jobs, results, &nResults)
    }

    close(jobs)
    wg.Wait()

    var sum int32 = 0
    var count int64 = 0
    for r := range results {
        count += 1
        sum += int32(r)
        if count == nResults {
            close(results)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(sum)
    fmt.Printf("number of result writes %d\n", nResults)
    fmt.Printf("Number of job writes %d\n", jobWrites)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few problems in your code.

#### Sending on closed channel

One general principle of using Go channels is

> **don't close a channel from the receiver side and don't close a channel if the channel has multiple concurrent senders**

*(https://go101.org/article/channel-closing.html)*

The solution for you is simple: don't have multiple concurrent senders, and then you can close the channel from the sender side.

Instead of starting millions of separate goroutine for each job you add to the channel, run one goroutine that executes the whole loop to add all jobs to the channel. And close the channel after the loop. The workers will consume the channel as fast as they can.

#### Data races by modifying shared variables in multiple goroutines

You're modifying two shared variables without taking special steps:

1. `nResults`, which you pass to the `countWrites *int64` in the worker.
2. `i` in the loop that writes to the jobs channel: you're adding 99 to it from multiple goroutines, making it unpredictable how many values you actually write to the `jobs` channel

To solve 1, there are many options, including using `sync.Mutex`. However since you're just adding to it, the easiest solution is to use `atomic.AddInt64(countWrites, 1)` instead of `*countWrites += 1`

To solve 2, don't use one goroutine per write to the channel, but one goroutine for the entire loop (see above)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply. I understand that you are suggesting this change 

```go func() {
  for i := 1; i <= 10000; i++ {
   if i%2 == 0 {
    i += 99
   }
   fmt.Printf("Value send to jobs is %d\n", i)
   jobs <- i
  }
  close(jobs)
 }()```

But I am still confused how would I be able to close the results channel after all results have been consumed? Should I still maintain a count of number of values that were sent to results or is there some better way?

Comment: As I understand main function is the receiver for results channel, also it is being sent values by multiple concurrent workers... so basically we shouldnt' close the channel in main ... but then without closing the channel we cant resolve deadlock... so maybe count has to be maintained?

Comment: Additionally, now I get this panic error 
```panic: too many concurrent operations on a single file or socket```

Comment: You shouldn't close the channel after all the results have been consumed: you should close it after all data has been **written** to it. You can read from a closed channel, and a range over a channel will complete when the channel is closed. But you can't write to a closed channel.

Comment: You should also not write to the result channel in a goroutine in the worker function, I didn't see that at first. The worker function is already running in a goroutine. Just send straight to the `results` channel from `worker`, not from another goroutine. That is probably causing the too many concurrent operations, and it also makes you mark the workgroup as Done when you don't know if the inner goroutines have completed.